# Permanently change date/time format for ls

Tags: bash

When I do `ls -l` I get

```
-rw-------  1 nifle None  17K Jul 15 01:48 .bash_history
-rwxr-xr-x  1 nifle None 1.2K Feb  9  2010 .bash_profile*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 nifle None 3.7K Mar 22 10:03 .bashrc*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 nifle None 3.7K Feb  9  2010 .bashrc~*
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 nifle None    0 Mar  6 17:31 .cpan/
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 nifle None    0 Jan  3  2011 .emacs.d/
 <snip>
```

How can I get the date/time format to allways be `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM` insted?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming GNU ls, from `info ls "Formatting file timestamps"`:

> ```
> `--time-style=STYLE'
>      List timestamps in style STYLE.  The STYLE should be one of the
>      following:
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> `long-iso'
>       List ISO 8601 date and time in minutes, e.g., `2002-03-30
>       23:45'.  These timestamps are shorter than `full-iso'
>       timestamps, and are usually good enough for everyday work.
>       This style is equivalent to `+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'.
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
>    You can specify the default value of the `--time-style' option with
> the environment variable `TIME_STYLE'; if `TIME_STYLE' is not set the
> default style is `locale'.
> ```

So put the following in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` and you are all set:

```
export TIME_STYLE=long-iso
```

Comment: Added a little more info to your answer.

Comment: This apeared to be dangerous on servers with loads of custom scripts who depend on the output of "ls"... :-(      ok, the scripts are wrong indeed..  but be aware of possible consequences

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs